# Can one poop in a seatless western-style toilet? how?

Tags: italy, tips-and-tricks, toilets

I was recently in Italy, and I noticed all public toilets had no seat. This happened around Rome and Tivoli mainly restaurants and bars, and also mid-range ones that had comfortable seating and were very nicely furnished. However, their toilet bowls are as tall as other northern European/American toilets and if I try to squat I would end up sitting in a dirty and cold ceramic rim (I wish they had squat toilets, it would make more sense).
Am I allowed to poop in such a toilet or are they designed for peeing only? If they are also for pooping what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: The dreaded "we're all adults here" there returns!

Comment: Most likely the seat was removed by vandals (or by staff to avoid the inevitable).

Comment: This usually ends up with a ton or two of toilet paper.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99684/why-do-many-public-bathrooms-in-israel-lack-toilet-seats

Comment: Also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61371/which-toilets-in-the-philippines-are-more-likely-to-have-seats-and-why-are-toil

Comment: It's debatable how 'dirty' a rim can be considered to be. At least one expert considers toilet seats in a domestic environment to represent a 'gold standard' of cleanliness - https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-20324304. Urine is generally very clean other than in rare cases where someone who has urinated has specific diseases, and even then, basic handwashing hygiene would mostly mitigate any direct hand contact with the rim. Also it's more likely for faeces to be present on a toilet seat than a rim since a toilet seat presents a broader surface for faeces to potentially come into contact with.

Comment: When I really had to use such toilets, I used the hand sanitizer to clean the rim as much as possible, then cover it with some toilet paper and did my business. I wish humans had the ability to hold it for days until we return home, but unfortunately, this business usually comes at wrong times and places.

Comment: Out of interest, where in Italy was this experience — north, south, urban, rural, …?  I’ve travelled in several parts of Northern + Central Italy in the last few years (Trieste, Florence, Genoa, and a few smaller towns in Tuscany), and have seen exclusively “standard Western toilets”, seats included.  I certainly remember squat toilets in Italy back in the 90’s, but in recent years everything I’ve seen has been fully modernised.

Comment: This was Around Tivoli and Rome, I added more info above.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow whatever the state of urine when it comes out, it is a skin irritant and will become more so as its components decompose into ammonia.  "Also, it's more likely for faeces to be present on a toilet seat than a rim since a toilet seat presents a broader surface for faeces to potentially come into contact with": the toilet in question has no seat.

Comment: It is not just the Italians, its mostly most of Europe AND the middle east.  Iraq / Jordan is the same way.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0EDA.jpg

Comment: @JonH I was born and raised in The Netherlands, and have been to multiple other European countries, and I have never seen toilets without a toilet seat (except some cases caused by clear vandalism, i.e. the broken seat was still next to the toilet), so I think citation needed for that "most of Europe".

Comment: @MarkRotteveel last I checked the netherlands isnt all of Europe. Sorry no citation but if you visit many areas throughout europe (saying europe does not imply simply the netherlands) you will see the same thing. Hard to cite a toilet. The middle east is the same way most of Iraq and Jordan have this issue as well.

Comment: @JonH: I'm from Austria, and my personal experience while traveling through Europe matches Mark's: The only cases of deliberately missing toilets seats I can remember are from public toilets in Italy---the most recent case being a camping site in Grado this summer. When I asked for the reason, it was claimed that they were easier to clean that way. (I can't say anything about the middle east, though.)

Comment: @JonH Selectively reading much? I said I was from The Netherlands _"and have been to multiple other European countries"_ (11 by my count), sure most of it was Western Europe, but I think that observation makes your assertion of "most of Europe" rather improbable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The canonical way is to wipe the rim thoroughly and then cover it with toilet paper. You sit down on that. Some squeamish persons are known to do that even if there is a proper seat. Some contact with the rim is typically unavoidable because, of course, the paper tends to shift and expose the ceramic.  The contact will be physically unpleasant because the ceramic feels cold. It may also be mentally unpleasant because of the vivid imagination of all the buggy bugs now being transferred to your skin.

But rest assured that the buggy bugs *already there* will either welcome them if they are nice, or take care of them if not.

All told, not touching the ceramic is mostly a cultural issue. We have all been conditioned as little children to not touch the toilet bowl, but that was at a time when we had our fingers in our orifices all the time, and probably the hand-washing conditioning was not completed yet. By now, hopefully, we have moved out of that developmental phase, so no damage done.

"Oh, just one more thing:" Works not only in Italy.

Answer (score 18):

Squatting ... dirty toilets ...

Please do **not** do the squatting with your feet on the ceramic rim. It holds strong until the time it does not hold your weight. There are anecdotally reports of deaths and at least one entry of [serious scientific literature about serious injuries](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32620331/).

The good useless custom we acquired with Coronavirus, i.e. to have hand sanitizers with us may actually be an helpful thing in travelling times: just use a ton of paper and some alcohol and then you can squat/seat on the ceramic rim. Enjoy!

Comment: Did you mean "alcohol" instead of "alcool"? I think the latter is in another language.

Comment: @Clockwork just the italian spelling ;) , thnaks.

Comment: Should be all-cool, maybe.

Comment: @EarlGrey did you mean "thanks" instead of "thnaks"? Just kidding, just kidding :)

Answer (score 16):

You have a few options:

- Sit down on the ceramic rim.
- Hover over the loo and hope you aim right.
- Bring something with you to clean and/or cover the rim.
- Or hold it till you are in a place where you feel better about sitting down.

There are also people who stand on the rim and squat there but that is risky for falling, higher risk of damage to the toilet. And a high risk of aiming to far back. While sometimes done it is not advised to use this method.

Comment: And of course, you have a roll of paper in the day pack.

Comment: These seems all awful options. What do you usually do? I wonder why Italians don't just use squat toilets.

Comment: @André I would just sit on the ceramic. It's not that much worse than sitting on the toilet seat, is it?

Comment: Reg. not advising the "stand on the rim": a part from the egoistic stand "it may be dirty where one may seat/hover, so I make it definitely dirty with my shoes", one should remember that broken ceramic/porcelain can easily cut through skin and blood vessels like a sharp blade.

Comment: @EarlGrey Indeed, there are some very graphic photos of such injuries. Perhaps a small chance but the potential consequences are severe.

Comment: @André they're usually public toilets in crowded places, if neither of those options work for you a fifth alternative is to look for a neighboring place with more comfortable toilets

Comment: As I recall [Paulie Walnuts chose to hold it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0EDA.jpg) until he could get back to the hotel.

Answer (score 5):

**WRT "Dirty and cold" toilet seat:** These are two separate issues.

**1. Dirty**
The porcelain is usually glazed--that is, covered with a thin layer of glass. A smooth glass surface is a fine place for bacteria to grow given the right conditions, but also among the easiest to clean. As other answers have suggested, you can carry some disinfectant (alcohol or **diluted** [chlorine-based](https://doh.wa.gov/sites/default/files/legacy/Documents/8340/970-216-Disinfect-en-L.pdf?uid=63d358bb3ae48) don't overdose!) and a paper towel to apply. This way you will be in no more danger of infection than with a toilet seat.

**2. Cold**
This may take a bit of getting used to, but it is not at all dangerous. Unless it has actual ice on it, that is, like this (minus the seat):

[image: picture of toilet with icicles]

Then you should chip the ice off, and use some sort of thermal insulation between your skin and the toilet, to avoid being frozen tight.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/what-does-wrt-mean

Comment: Just a note about disinfectants; they need time to work, just applying them then immediately  wiping off won't be very effective.